# Flask- Save data from database to list

Tags: python, postgresql

I write flask aplication and in this app i want do get all users from my postgresql databese.
I want to save my all users to list of User objects but i have an error  "tuple indices must be integers, not str".

```
class User:
   def __init__(self, UserId, UserName, City):
       self.UserId = UserId
       self.UserName = UserName
       self.City = City



@app.route('/users', methods=['GET'])
def get_users():
    users = []
    connection = get_connection_to_database()
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    query = 'select UserId, UserName,City from Users'
    cursor.execute(query)

    for  row in cursor:
        users.append(row(['UserId'], row['UserName'], row['City']))

    connection.close()

    return jsonpickle.encode(users)
```

Maybe someone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: You should always provide your full error message for additional information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User(['UserId'] should be row(['UserId'] .
In addition you want to return list of lists.
Each list represents a user.
So your code should create a separate list or dict for each user.
Use row [0], etc in order to get the data

Comment: You are right. I fix this but i have got the same error.

Comment: See my answer again. Row is a tuple , not a dict